# nasm instruction expected inb outb

Tags: assembly, kernel, x86-64, nasm, osdev

I'm getting an error compiling the following nasm code:

```
global _ports_read
global _ports_write
extern _ports_port
extern _ports_data

section .text
bits 64

_ports_read:
    inb [_ports_data], [_ports_port]
    ret

_ports_write:
    outb [_ports_data], [_ports_port]
    ret
```

The error is:

```
.../ports.asm:10: error: parser: instruction expected
.../ports.asm:14: error: parser: instruction expected
```

This is pointing to the lines `inb [_ports_data], [_ports_port]` and `outb [_ports_data], [_ports_port]`.

How do I fix this?

Context: I am writing my own operating system kernel and I'm linking this assembly so that I can communicate with the hardware ports on x86_64 in my C code.

**EDIT**

My assembly is now as follows (hopefully all the mistakes gone)

```
...

_ports_read:
    mov dx, _ports_port
    inb al, dx
    mov _ports_data, al
    ret

_ports_write:
    mov dx, _ports_port
    mov al, _ports_data
    outb dx, al
    ret
```

Comment: [`in`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/in) and [`outb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/out) don't take memory addresses as parameters. You need to look at moving the vales to the appropriate registers supported by those instructions. You should also not pass parameters to functions using global variables. You need to consider looking at the [x86-64 System V ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) calling convention since you are using GCC and integrating with 64-bit code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch of course, thanks! and I was just temporarily using global variables to make it simpler

Comment: @MichaelPetch I believe I fixed the assembly (see edited question), but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: The x86 instruction are actually called `in` and `out`. NASM can infer the size of the data by the register. An 8 bit register (AL) implies byte input. AX would be word input. Simply change the instructions to `out` and `in` rather `outb` and `inb`

Comment: I posted a link in my first comment to a simplified overview of the calling convention. The first parameter of a C function in 64-bit code is passed in RDI and the second in RSI. You can simply move the appropriate parameter into DX and AL rather than using globals.  Its actually easier to not to use global veriables.

Comment: In your updated code you should consider putting square brackets around memory operands when using NASM.

Comment: @DavidCallanan `in` and `out` always take `dx` and `al` or `ax` for operands where `dx` is the port number and `al` or `ax` is the datum to transfer.  You cannot use different registers or memory operands.  As for your updated code: please make a [mcve].  The code you posted is not an MCVE.

Comment: @MichaelPetch that makes sense, I just noticed that myself. I'll try those changes, thanks for the help.

Comment: `outb dx, al` still doesn't assemble; you still forgot to change the mnemonic to `out`.  Also, don't edit answers into your question; post answers as answers if you want to answer your own quesiton.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry I wasn't putting an answer in my question, I was just fixing some assembly mistakes but still getting the same error. I should've noted that in the question

Comment: `mov _ports_data, al` doesn't assemble on its own; NASM requires `[]` around memory operands.  (So `mov dx, _ports_port` is a mov-immediate of the symbol address, or of an equ constant.)  But seriously, if these are function you call, just pass args / return value in registers, not via globals!  Or if the caller is asm, just inline an `out` or `in` instruction.  Or in C, you can find a header with inline asm definitions of `inb` / `inw` / `inl` macros / wrapper functions that avoid call/ret code size overhead, and are thread-safe instead of using nasty globals.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok thanks, I got it compiling anyway -- although I'm not sure if the code is actually working